# Is it possible to connect a slot or regular function from one class to a slot or regular function from another class? (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

To be specific to my problem I've been trying to connect a a slot from one class to a regular function of another class. I'm trying to do this so I can close the ui of one the main window from a dialog window. I tried everything I could possibly think of but it seems like every time I think of something to try the Qt compiler shuts me down by throwing some error or not working for no apparent reason such as when I did this

```
function(Ui::MainWindow *ui)
{     
copy = ui; // copy is a pointer declared as Ui::MainWindow *copy in the dialog class
}
```

I tried this so I could close the main window from the copy pointer in the dialog class and although it compiled for that, it wouldn't compile when I tried to use it in another function of that class even though it was a class variable. After that I then realized that I should be able to connect the two functions from the main function. I wrote this

```
QObject::connect(&i, SIGNAL(on_passInput_returnPressed()), &w, SLOT(initalizer()));
```

The above compiles but when debugging I discovered it never gets executed and not sure why despite the fact that the SIGNAL on_passInput_returnPressed() is actually declared as slot in the class header. If that is the reason why it doesn't get executed how do I connect the slot from the dialog class to a regular function from the MainWindow class? There must be a way because I spent a day practically thinking about this non-stop and can't think of any other way given the nature of object scopes (in OOP) on top of the fact that the pointer thing I thought of didn't work.

Also I just now recreated the error from the pointer thing described above here it is.

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MainWindow'
 copy->close();
     ^
```

Again this error is referring to trying to access the close function via the copy pointer from another function in the same class as the pointer assignment that worked in the other function. The copy pointer is declared as follows in the class header. Also in case you're wondering, yes, the pointer assignment written above does get executed. I checked via debugging.

```
private:
    Ui::InitalPrompt *ui;
    Ui::MainWindow *copy;
```

If you need more info just let me know what you need and I'll edit this post with it. I've obsessively tried so much I can think so much so that I've given up without further help due to how unforgiving Qt has been with me.

Also if there's a way of doing what I'm trying to do with the new Qt5 syntax of the connect function can you please give me the exact thing to type because despite looking into that new syntax myself I can't get it to compile for the life of me. (and yes I'm using Qt5) That's why the code above is written as old-fashion syntax.

Added the following as suggested to do so in a reply which is the class of the copy pointer.

```
#include "initalprompt.h"
#include "ui_initalprompt.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>

InitalPrompt::InitalPrompt(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InitalPrompt)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

InitalPrompt::~InitalPrompt()
{
    delete ui;
}

void InitalPrompt::on_passInput_returnPressed()
{
    pass = ui->passInput->text();


}

void InitalPrompt::reject()
{

    QMessageBox::StandardButton resBtn = QMessageBox::Yes;
    bool changes = false;
    if (changes) {
        resBtn = QMessageBox::question( this, "APP_NAME",
                                        tr("Are you sure?\n"),
                                        QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Yes,
                                        QMessageBox::Yes);
    }
    if (resBtn == QMessageBox::Yes) {
        QDialog::reject();

    }
    // the only issue is with the statment below don't know why
    copy->close();
}
 void InitalPrompt::catcher(Ui::MainWindow *ui)
{
    copy = ui;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to close the main window from the `ui` pointer?

Comment: First - you can't connect function to function, it's just not how signals-slots work. Moreover, it's meaningless cause it's nothing more that just call one function from another, so why to complicate? Second - Ui::MainWindow is not really the Window - it's the class generated by Qt to configure and setup the GUI from xml .ui file. Third - IMO, you should revise your architecture - if you are trying to close the MainWindow from dialog (except may be when you want to close app), it looks like, that MainWindow is not the really 'Main'.

Comment: @Mike yes at least that was the case before I tried using the connect function in main.

Comment: @Rinold I complicate because it's not that simple due to the nature of objects. Also MainWindow::ui is a pointer that controls the window. Also the reason why I didn't flip the architecture is because of action in the app is gonna happen in the main window with the current architecture. (I'll make that flip if resorted to do so but trying to avoid it)

Comment: There is a very simple solution to your problem. Emit a *signal* (*declare it as a signal, not as a slot*) in `InitalPrompt::reject` and connect that signal to the `close` slot of your `MainWindow` object. You don't have to overcomplicate your code by passing pointers around, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid use of incomplete type" means the compiler does not (yet) have a definition for the class when it reaches that line. In the header file that contains your copy pointer, include a forward declaration above the class declaration (the file would look something liek this):

```
#ifndef BLAH_BLAH_H
#define BLAH_BLAH_H

/*All of your normal #includes here*/

namespace Ui {
    class InitialPrompt;
    class MainWindow; //Note the forward declaration here
}

#include "mainwindow.h"

class BlahBlah
{
    /*Class stuff here*/
private:
    Ui::InitalPrompt *ui;
    Ui::MainWindow *copy;
};

#endif //BLAH_BLAH_H
```

If you post the entirety of your class file that has the *copy, we can look further into it.

Comment: I tried your edit but it didn't get rid of the error and sure I'll post the code of the class file.

Comment: Can you make a https://gist.github.com/ with all of your files? That way I can save them locally and try to compile them myself and I'll be able to help you further.

Comment: Okay, I only reuploaded the files that I changed: https://gist.github.com/Pinguinsan/6e0d9e005160f842b2a79554f80b0302

Changes: 
1.) In main.cpp, the exec() call will block until that window is closed, so the connect() calls should occur before the exec()
2.) Ui::MainWindow is actually just the form, so it doesn't have a close(). So instead, copy was changed from a Ui::MainWindow * to a MainWindow *
3.) You were attempting to use on_passInput_returnPressed() as a signal, but declared it as a slot. I made an actual signal passInputReturnPressed and (continued...)

Comment: connected it to on_passInput_returnPressed() and MainWindow::initialize() (which is what you were trying to do initially).  

4.) I overrode QDialog::keyPressEvent() in InitialDialog to be enable to emit the signal when the return key is pressed.  

5.) I hid the InitialDialog in on_passInput_returnPressed(); as well as showed the MainWindow. You could alternatively just call close() on the InitialDialog instance (this->close()).  

  

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks so much I can't thank you enough. I after studying your explanations and code I understand your changes. I just want mention certain things that came as a shock to me. 1) I wouldn't have thought you could assign Ui::MainWindow pointer to a MainWindow pointer nor did I think you could make a pointer like that without the Ui part of the declaration since that's not how it was generated by Qt. 2) I would've never thought that making a signal and slot have the same name would be legal (because I assume a clash between the header your implementation of the slot continued...

Comment: the generated header of the signal. 3) I also didn't realize that the execution piece you added would result in the behavior that it does. (still learning event driven programming as it's not taught in school)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can either:

- call `w->initalizer()` directly from `on_passInput_returnPressed()` or
- define a signal `signal_on_passInput_returnPressed()` in your ui class and emit that signal from `on_passInput_returnPressed()`. Then

  `QObject::connect(&i, SIGNAL(signal_on_passInput_returnPressed()), &w, SLOT(initalizer()));`

should work.

For example:

```
class Whatever : 
   public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT

  void on_passInput_returnPressed();

signals:
  void signal_on_passInput_returnPressed();
};

void Whatever::on_passInput_returnPressed() {

   emit signal_on_passInput_returnPressed();
}
```

Comment: Is the first option you give really possible given that the only way it could possibly happen is if the on_passInput_returnPressed() had a MainWindow object as a parameter? (keep in mind that function was created via the Designer not me directly) Also in reference to your second option I don't think that's possible given that in my experience signals can't implemented.

Comment: Yes, you need to have access to `w` either by a parameter to `on_passInput_returnPressed()`  or  better yet, as a data member to the dialog class. You could add `QMainWindow* m_w` as a private data member to the dialog class and set it during construction (, by adding an extra parameter to the constructor), or else, by adding a setter function, e.g. `setMainWindow(QMainWindow* newVal) {m_w = newVal;}` It is still much cleaner to use a signal IMHO. I updated the answer with an example.